# In Harry Potter, why don't they petrify Peter Pettigrew?

Tags: harry-potter

One thing that I've often gotten frustrated about in the Harry Potter movies is how simple it would be to petrify people in order to bring them to justice.

Why is the petrifying curse so rarely used despite being so handy? Especially in *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, where Pettigrew's "still being alive situation" could have saved Sirius's life and made him a free man.

Comment: What 'Petrifying curse'?

Comment: Because they don't. The plot required Pettigrew to escape.

Comment: @Mithrandir He's probably asking about the Full Body-Bind Curse, *Petrificus Totalus*.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Ah, I was thinking like the Basilisk :P

Comment: @Mithrandir Right, my initial reaction having just read the question title was "Well, the basilisk is dead, and it would be horrendously irresponsible (**even by Hogwarts standards**) to do so anyway."

Comment: Because...he's a rat?

Comment: So, There is no reason what so ever ? Other than Plot of course (often, the movie doesn't show things that the book explains very well. )

Comment: @Paperplane probably for the same reasons normal people don't shoot everybody they see committing a crime, they consider it unneeded, overly harmful, or an invasion of privacy.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Well, Hermione does petrify Neville in first year with out a seconds thought.

Comment: @Paperplane because she considered it absolutely necessary to save more people's lives. She was remorseful about it afterward.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ Pettigrew is a murderer ... Neville is a little boy. Soooo

Comment: @Paperplane yeah, but she thought (rightfully) many more people would die if she didn't petrify neville.  Plus, she's a first year student. Her thinking might be very different than the magical police.

Comment: @Paperplane They thought that two fully qualified wizards (Sirius and Lupin) plus Harry and Hermione were capable of keeping Peter under control, without the need to petrify him (which would have made him considerably harder to extract from the Shrieking Shack and Whomping Willow). They just didn't factor in Lupin forgetting to take his Wolfbane Potion and transforming once they reached the Hogwarts grounds.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Your answer makes perfect sense. Thank you very much :) (although my heart will always want to petrify that horrible little rat)

Comment: Besides, the *preferred* form of subduing someone (for whatever reason) is the Stunning Spell. The advantage of this is that it renders a person *unconscious*, as opposed to the Full Body-Bind, which might allow someone skilled at non-verbal or wandless magic to cast a spell, as well as allowing the person thus subdued to see and hear normally, and thus perceive things that their captors might not want them to.

Answer (score 7):

In the books they chain him to Lupin and Ron:

> Black conjured heavy manacles from thin air; soon Pettigrew was
>   upright again, left arm chained to Lupin's right, right arm to Ron's
>   left.

*Harry Potter and The Prisoner of Azkhaban, chapter 19*

He also had no wand and there were two adult wizards + Ron, Harry and Hermione to constrain Peter if necessary.

All in all - they considered it safe just to chain Peter and let him walk instead of using some kind of immobilizing charm.

The events just turned ugly when Lupin transformed which allowed Peter to grab his wand and flee.

Comment: It was utterly thoughtless of them to think that chains would have any effect. Sirius and Lupin both have intimate knowledge of how Animagi work (Sirius _is_ one, ferchrissakes), and they know that a wand is not needed. Transforming and trying to escape as a rat was the obvious thing for Pettigrew to do, and the others were complete idiots for not considering this. But then, plot must advance…

Answer (score 1):

Aside from human error there is no plausible explanation made explicit in the book except for plot convenience and lazy writing.

There’s no fun in that so I have conjured up a relatively plausible albeit purely speculative explanation that is at least backed up by some evidence.

Peter Pettigrew is a relatively powerful and talented wizard (e.g. he learned how to transform into a rat while he was still a student at Hogwarts), as well as a very sly individual who has been hiding out and looking over his shoulder for more than a decade. There are also numerous examples of spells and potions that can confuse or even control people, including the [Confundus Charm](https://harry-potter-compendium.fandom.com/wiki/Confundus_Charm) (which is mentioned soon afterwards in POA), the [Befuddlement Draught](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Befuddlement_Draught), or even the [Imperius Curse](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Imperius_Curse).

It is therefore plausible Peter uses magic to confuse people and to coerce them into making decisions that benefit him. Whether he cast some kind of charm long before the climax of POA or in the moment (wizards can perform magic even without wands, though maybe not as strongly), clearly it is otherwise impossible that between the three teenagers and two adults in that room not one of them thought chaining a dangerous and slippery animagus to an injured boy would be a good idea.

On top of that you have Lupin, who after decades of being careful suddenly forgets about being a werewolf and messes everything up and almost gets everyone killed.

Peter’s protective charm isn’t strong enough to confuse people enough to let him go outright but it can cloud their judgement enough to provide him with an opportunity for escape due to poor decision making.

It helps that no one was in a particularly clear state of mind:

- Ron was seriously injured and shocked at the revelation that his pet was a man all along.
- Harry quickly went from thinking his parents were betrayed by Sirius to realizing it was Peter.
- Hermione has worn herself thin taking too many classes all year and messing with time travel.
- Lupin is about to turn into a werewolf plus he realizes he’s been wrong about his friends for years.
- Sirius has been in Azkaban for twelve years and barely managed to hold on to his sanity. Plus he hadn’t planned on keeping Peter alive at all anyway.

The three teenagers are also inclined to follow the lead of the two older, more experienced wizards.

Peter used a similar technique to convince Sirius to make him the secret keeper for the Potters. He used it again when he escaped from Sirius for the first time and faked his death. Maybe he didn’t have to use magic for those tricks but either way it is evidence of his ability to manipulate people and escape from sticky situations.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a specific spell to petrify someone. In the previous films the people who were petrified were done so by the Basilisk and had to be cured by a potion from mandrakes.

There are spells such as *Petrificus Totalus* which is a body-bind curse.

Comment: Petrificus Totalus. That's what OP meant.